# Iframe floating around on IOS

Tags: html, ios, css, iframe, responsive-design

I have an iframe wrapped with a iframe-container div which is taking 25% of the screen from right, all the elements are inside the iframe.

There is a textbox input field in iframe, upon touch, all elements are behaving properly and the windows adjusts as per the keyboard of IPAD however the moment I start typing, i.e any character is being added in the text input the whole layout of iframe-container shifts towards left and then after few more character inputs disappears completely.

Refer to the image below:

Screen one (this is the desired UI all the time)

[image]

Screen Two (Messed up UI after any character is entered)

[image]

Even this layout disappears when more characters are added.

I went through few solved issues of iframe with IOS devices and followed few concepts and solutions from there.

- Iframe in this case does not have any scroll added to it. A div inside the iframe is being scrolled
- Have also tried adding `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` to the scrollable div and this did not helped either.
- Was using VH for height, tried removing them and used `PX` no luck there too.

NOTE: A lot of jQuery is being used of UI adjustments, not particularly for iframe and the cross button basically toggles the iframe-wrapper div (simple hide and show).

Thanks!!

**EDIT**

I have found the problem, now I need the solution for this.
Safari is automatically adding `background-position` property and setting it to `Initial`, manually override to `no-repeat` fixes the problem.

I tried adding jQuery css property for `background-position` but I guess it is somehow not being applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is weird but I discovered 0 property was not working and the moment I added left and top instead of `bottom: 0` everything was fine!!